# store database table rows into an object in java

Tags: java, object, jdbc, jdbctemplate

In my project i am using jdbcTemplate class to fetch data from database's table,so i need to store the list that getting from jdbcTemplate queryForList() method into a java.lang.Object instance.

something like this:

```
List<Object> dataObject = JdbcTemplate.queryForList(SQL_LIST_QUERY, new Object[]{},
new ObjectMapper());
```

the above code is not implemented yet because i am replacing a dto class with object.i am using row-mappers also. how can i achieve this?,if you need more details please mention it in comments.

please explain it with sample codes.

Comment: what do You want to achieve? You want to have a list of entities/dto's/POJOs filled with the query result? queryForList only works on simple types like list of Integer or String. For complex object You implemented You just want a query() method with a RowMapper

Comment: i can't specify a dto or rowmapper i can only specify a common one for each query(a common mapper), that's what i am actually looking for

Answer (score 0):

You just need to iterate through list of objects and map each of them to the target. There is an example https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-querying-examples/

Comment: This could've been a comment rather than an answer!